# Flutter hide elements based on request/response - Error setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and I need to hide one element after getting response from server , I am using visibility property but still I am getting issue , And please correct me if I am doing in wrong way.

initially , I am declaring one variable _isGot with false and based on this value, I am setting the visible of property of element ,  after getting response I am making _isGot as true and setting this value with setState(), but it s throwing error.

**KlimaticState**

```
class KlimaticStateFul extends StatefulWidget {
 String _name;

 KlimaticStateFul(this._name);

  @override
 _KlimaticStateFulState createState() => _KlimaticStateFulState();
 }
```

**_KlimaticStateFulState**

```
    class _KlimaticStateFulState extends State<KlimaticStateFul> {
        bool _isGot = false;
         @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return Scaffold(
             appBar: AppBar(
             backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
             centerTitle: true, 
            title: Text(
                 'Klimatic',
                   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
             )),
           body: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
              Container(
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                 image: AssetImage("icons/raining.jpeg"),
                 fit: BoxFit.cover,
               ),
               ),
            ), 
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 350, 0, 0),
        child: _getWeatherData(context),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 300, 0, 0),
        child: Visibility(
            child: Text(
          _temp.toString() + 'F Temp',
          style: tempStyle(),
        ),
        visible: !_isGot),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
 }



        FutureBuilder<Response> _getWeatherData(BuildContext context) {
         print("Log:_getWeatherData with $_city");
         return FutureBuilder<Response>(
    future: Provider.of<PostApiService>(context)
        .getWeatherData(_city, '90dc4b035584894abff118a13d2a6d66'),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        final Map data = json.decode(snapshot.data.bodyString);
        return _buildPosts(context, data);
      } else {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
         });
      }

      Container _buildPosts(BuildContext context, Map data) {
//print('******Data************** $data');
if (data == null)
  return Container(
    child: Text('No data found'),
  );
else {
  double _temp = data['main']['temp'];
  print(data['main']);
    this._temp = _temp;
    _saveData(_temp.toString() + 'F');
    setState(() {
      _isGot = true;
    });
  return Container(
      child: Text(
    _temp.toString() + 'F',
    style: tempStyle(),
     ));
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problem**

1. `build()` gets called
2. `FutureBuilder` triggers `getWeatherData()`
3. The future isn't finished yet so it shows the loading
4. Then the future finishes and now since connection state is done, `_buildPost()` gets called
5. If there's data, `setState()` gets called and that would make
   `build()` get called again, but there you get an error, because
   `build()` would be called recursively before returning the final widget, that means
   without having finished to build the subtree of widgets and that's
   not allowed by the framework.

**The Solution**

Wrap the widgets that depends on the future with `FutureBuilder`, in your case you  could wrap the `Stack` with `FutureBuilder` instead of putting it inside of one of the `Containers`. This way you can access the snapshot data from the `Visibility` widget and set the `visible` property according to that.

**Suggestions**

- This `json.decode(snapshot.data.bodyString)` could be done in the
  future call and return a `Future<Map<String, dynamic>>`, then you can
  access that map with `snapshot.data`
- Try to use the methods `snapshot.hasData` and `snapshot.hasError`

Answer (score 0):

To make widget hide show you have to return widgets conditionally 
Example :-

```
Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 300, 0, 0),
            child: _isGot ? Text('F Temp',) : Container(),
          )
```

we are returning blank container on false flag.

Comment: Before calling request itself , I need to show that element and after getting response I need to hide it

Comment: To show that element  Before calling request itself give "true" default value to _isGot variable that will work